# Update database table row value when an checkbox is checked in the gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, checkbox, auto-update

I have a asp.net gridview page and I've added checkbox column to it. I am using JavaScript to select multiple checkboxes at once if the row values are similar. Now I want to update my database row value to '1' when I select the checkbox in the gridview. Can you please help me to write the logic?

I tired few logics but it is not working and I am getting error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to handle checkbox click event 
  function handleCheckboxClick() {
    var invNumber = $(this).val();
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + invNumber + '"]');
    checkboxes.prop('checked', isChecked);
  }
  // Function to handle "Select All" checkbox click event 
  function handleSelectAllClick() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="invoice"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
  }
  // Attach event handlers to checkboxes 
  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"][name="inv"]', handleCheckboxClick);
  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"][name="selectAll"]', handleSelectAllClick);
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+update+asp+database+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.